# How to add a TXT record value to AWS Amazon Route 53 so that my Outlook will have the same domain ending?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, outlook, office365, amazon-route53

I was asked to input some values in the TXT record fields on Amazon AWS Route 53 when following this: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Verify-your-domain-in-Office-365-6383f56d-3d09-4dcb-9b41-b5f5a5efd611?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

For some strange reason, it doesn't get recognized on 365 Office website. 
Any idea why? 
What am I doing wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NMHr.png
[image]

Comment: Do you have any other TXT records? Some DNS providers require the values to be in one entry

Comment: I have it on a .pro domain too. 
If I remove it it will be fixed?